# how to validate date with simple-react-validator with momentJS in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, momentjs

I am using [simple-react-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-validator#date) and Moment.js i have to input date from user in date type input element but simple-react-validator didn't validating moment date type object although in its documentation they said date must be moment object type.

```
this.state = {
    a : {
        b : {
            c:{
                value:moment()
            }
        }
    }
}

-----------
chanageDate(e){
    const { name, value, type } = e.target;
    const aState = cloneDeep( this.state.a );
    aState['b'][name]['value'] = moment(value);
    this.setState(
        {
            a: aState
        }
    );
}

-----------
<input type="date" name='c' value={a.b.c['value'].format("YYYY-MM-DD")} onChange={this.chanageDate.bind(this)}/>
{
    validatorInstance.message("DepartureDate", a.b.c['value'] , 'date')
}
```

Comment: Where is the comparison logic?

Comment: @AminPaks have u used simple react validator?